# JQuery onclick listener for anchor class on ace:dataTable paginator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, icefaces

I want to add a click event listener for pages in ace:dataTable paginator.

Paginator looks like this.

```
<span id="yui-pg0-0-pages" class="ui-paginator-pages">
    <span class="ui-paginator-page ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-paginator-current-page ui-state-active">1</span>
        <a page="2" class="ui-paginator-page ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#">2</a>
        <a page="3" class="ui-paginator-page ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#">3</a>
        <a page="4" class="ui-paginator-page ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#">4</a>
        <a page="5" class="ui-paginator-page ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#">5</a>
        <a page="6" class="ui-paginator-page ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#">6</a>
</span>
```

I tried to add a click listener for the class **ui-paginator-page**. This fires only for the first time.
I used jQuery on(), live() and click().
All of them fire only once.
I want it to be fired every time user clicks on the class **ui-paginator-page**.
How can I do that.

Here is the ace:dataTable demo. http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=aceMenu&exp=dataExporterBean

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/prollygeek/txS7a/

```
$("#yui-pg0-0-pages .ui-paginator-page").on("click",function(){alert("hi")})
```

there must be something wrong else where !

Comment: oh  the problem is href , you should remove it !

Comment: Is there any other alternatives to do this without removing href? This code generated from ICEFaces library. So removing it may be complected.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click','.ui-paginator-pages > a.ui-state-default',function(e)
{
 alert(e.value);
});
});
```

Comment: It doesn't fire at all.

Comment: try now i updated my answer i missed . in class names

Comment: Still it doesn't fire.

Comment: try now i forgot to rename class names

Comment: that doesn't fire either

Comment: remove href="#" from anchor tag